# I'm simply trying to create a file in python3, but the standard answers are not working

Tags: python-3.x, file, new-operator

Simple task with answers all over the web. I just can't get any of them to work. When I run the code below on macOS, I get the following error messages:

open error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'test_60'

Path error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'test_60'

mknod error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

The complete test program follows. What stupid thing am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from pathlib import Path
import os

db_file = "test_60"
#
try:
    open(db_file, 'a').close()
except OSError as e:
    print('open error:', e)
try:
    Path(db_file).touch()
except OSError as e1:
    print('Path error:', e1)

try:
    os.mknod(db_file)
except OSError as e2:
    print('mknod error:', e2)
```

Comment: Directory permissions?

Comment: See my comment below. Directory Permissions may be why the os.makenod() doesn't work.

Comment: It's likely that PythonRunner and TextMate are running the script under a different shell/user. What permissions do you have set for the folder? I also get the error for `os.mknod` when running the script directly, regardless of permissions.